# Would app will be deleted from GSuite marketplace if marked unlisted from Chromewebstore dashboard

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store, google-workspace

As a developer, 4 weeks back I have unpublished GSuite marketplace app(Spreadsheet addon) through Chrome web store developer dashboard. On Chrome web store dashboard status is updated. But it is still visibile in GSuite marketplace search listing (don't know why). Probably this is Google bug that even after marking unpublish it is visible in public marketplace.
Not getting much quick support for requests raised to Google to delete this app from marketplace.

Query: I want this app to be deleted from GSuite marketplace. My question is if I mark my app as "unlisted" through chrome web store developer dashboard, then will it remove GSuite marketplace listing? Can anyone please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

From this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/faq#how_can_i_create_additional_owners_of_a_marketplace_application):

**How can I manage and uninstall the applications I have installed from the Marketplace?**

> By clicking on "Manage Apps" on the top right of the Marketplace,
>   users can view the applications they have installed. From there they
>   can rate, review and uninstall applications (unless admin-installed).

There's also [Delete an app in Gsuite Marketplace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6216211?hl=en) which states the same steps.

Comment: I am not taking about managing or removing app from domain as admin. I am talking about deleting an app from G-Suite marketplace as "developer".
 As a developer, I have published this app and deployed on GSuite marketplace. But around a month back, I don't want this app to be available to anyone, so I have unpublished this app through chrome webstore dashboard, but the problem is it still showing in marketplace publicly. 
Probably this is the bug at Google end. I want it to remove this app from GSuite marketplace listing.